# What combination of keys do I need to enter complex formula in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've created a conditional `SUM` formula:

```
 =SUM(IF($G$14:$G$5002="Liz S Salary",IF($Q$14:$Q$5000>=Summary!$F$6,IF($Q$14:$Q$5000<=Summary!$F$7,$R$14:$R$5000,0),0),0))
```

The formula needs to be saved to an Excel cell and show the result. I've done this before and had to press a combination of keys to insert the formula into the cell, only I can't remember now. All the other older formulas work, just need to update this one. Please help, as I haven't found an answer by googling.

Answer (score 3):

The formula you have entered is an array-formula, that is it is a formula which works on an array of values.

There are several excellen resources for learning about array formulas online, this quote from [one of them](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) should tell you what you need to do to get your formula to work.

> To enter a formula as an array formula, type the formula in the cell
>   and press the CTRL SHIFT and ENTER keys at the same time rather then
>   just ENTER. You must do this the first time you enter the formula and
>   whenever you edit the formula later. If you do this properly, Excel
>   will display the formula enclosed in curly braces { }. You do not type
>   in the braces -- Excel will display them automatically. If you neglect
>   to enter the formula with CTRL SHIFT ENTER, the formula may return a
>   #VALUE error or return an incorrect result.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.

Comment: @CharlieRB I expanded on it a bit, though it is really just quoting from a different webpage. I dunno how much more there really is to say about why she couldn't get it to work?

Comment: Good job. This is much better than a single line of text. Using a link to reference material is always good to validate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cell you want the result displayed in, then, if you can't directly paste the formula there, select the formula input box above the spreadsheet and paste your formula into that box.

If there is a problem with how the result is displayed after you enter this formula, then I think there is another problem, perhaps with the G, Q, or R columns that this cell references.

In other words, if your cell now says "#VALUE!" or "#REF!" then you have a data source problem, not a formula saving problem.

You can do a dependancy check to see where a formula gets its data from, that can be found on the "Ribbon" (the top bar with all the menus) by going to "Formulas->Trace Precedents" in the Formula Auditing section.

If you don't have access to a mouse, then you can use your arrow keys to select the cell you want this pasted into, and press CTRL+v to paste the formula (assuming you copied it to the clipboard with CTRL+c or your mouse) into the highlighted cell. If your arrow keys don't move the highlighted cell, trying pressing ESC and that should get your focus back onto the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

In `Excel 2013` you can use `SUMIFS` function for summing with multiple conditions. That's preferable, because it's simpler and faster and doesn't need "array entry".

Try this version -

`=SUMIFS($R$14:$R$5000,$G$14:$G$5000,"Liz Salary",$Q$14:$Q$5000,">="&Summary!$F$6,$Q$14:$Q$5000,"<="&Summary!$F$7)`

Note: Sum range is always at the start in `SUMIFS`......and I changed one of your ranges because it ended at row `5002` rather than `5000` like the others, all ranges need to be the same size and shape in `SUMIFS`